# WebStorm: Mark method to be overridden in ES6 base class

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

How to hide `Unresolved function or method addLayers()` notification? So WebStorm would know that this method is overridden/declared in extended/child class.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved: We can use [`@abstract`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-abstract.html) JSDoc. Also we need to turn off `class-methods-use-this` rule in eslint config. [Github issue for eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8441).